# Is there a way to call an async function from outer scope?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

```
getPhotoStatus();
async function getPhotoStatus () {
    let res = await fetchPhoto('/photos/19062657811.png');
    console.log(res);
}
async function fetchPhoto(uri) {
    const status = fetch(uri).then(response => response.status);
    return status;
}
```

I have this code here, it works fine but removing getPhotoStatus() and awaiting the fetch function directly in fetchPhoto() returns a Promise, is there another way to do this instead of making double functions basically to get the value of a Promise directly from the outer scope?

Comment: `await` is basically just syntactic sugar for using `.then()`.

Comment: "*awaiting the fetch function directly in fetchPhoto() returns a Promise*" - hm, `await` *never* returns a promise, so I don't understand what you did. Can you please [edit] your question to also include the non-working code?